# How to load some data and showing it immediately using loader, loading from json: android app

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, loader

I'm using `google book API` and showing result of books in my app. For loading books i'm  using loader `callback` methods to load books in background. Problem is loader return all books collectively at the time of finishing of loading. But, I want to show books immediately as they being loading in the background by the loaders.
How to do it?
Please response fast....
Thanks in advance....:)

```
  @Override
public Loader<List<Book>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new BookLoader(this, preferenceLoader());
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Book>> loader, List<Book> books) {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mEmptyView.setText(R.string.empty_view_text);

    mAdapter.clear();

    if (books != null && !books.isEmpty()) {
        mAdapter.addAll(books);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<List<Book>> loader) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onLoaderReset(): ");
    mAdapter.clear();
}

private String preferenceLoader() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String inTitle = sharedPreferences.getString(
            getString(R.string.setting_in_title_key),
            getString(R.string.settings_option_none_label));
    String inAuthor = sharedPreferences.getString(
            getString(R.string.setting_in_author_key),
            getString(R.string.settings_option_none_label));
    String inPublisher = sharedPreferences.getString(
            getString(R.string.setting_in_publisher_key),
            getString(R.string.settings_option_none_label));
    String printType = sharedPreferences.getString(
            getString(R.string.settings_print_type_key),
            getString(R.string.settings_print_type_default));
    String filter = sharedPreferences.getString(
            getString(R.string.settings_filter_key),
            getString(R.string.settings_filter_default));
    String orderBy = sharedPreferences.getString(
            getString(R.string.settings_order_by_key),
            getString(R.string.settings_order_by_default));

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "filter: " + filter + " orderBy: " + orderBy + " printType: " + printType);

    Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(GOOGLE_BOOK_QUERY);
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();

    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("q", mQuery
            .replace(" ", "%20"));

    if (!inTitle.equals("None")) {
        uriBuilder.appendEncodedPath("+intitle:" + inTitle);
    }
    if (!inPublisher.equals("None")) {
        uriBuilder.appendEncodedPath("+inpublisher:" + inPublisher);
    }
    if (!inAuthor.equals("None")) {
        uriBuilder.appendEncodedPath("+inauthor:" + inAuthor);
    }

    if (!printType.equals("None")) {
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(getString(
                R.string.settings_print_type_key),
                printType);
    }
    if (!filter.equals("None")) {
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(getString(
                R.string.settings_filter_key),
                filter);
    }
    if (!orderBy.equals("None")) {
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(getString(
                R.string.settings_order_by_key),
                orderBy);
    }

    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("maxResults", "40");

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "uriBuilder: " + uriBuilder.toString());

    return uriBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried on your own to solve this? Can you at least describe in the words of your users how that should work?